# How to extract the original image from a set of modified images?

Tags: image-processing

Given a set of N images, where each image can be described as

```
image = baseImage + uniqueOverlay
```

and the "uniqueOverlay" was added onto the "baseImage" using an unknown alpha value, which is constant for all images, how can I extract the unknown "baseImage"?

I have a feeling an algorithm for this already exists, but I am not able to find it as I am not very experience in image processing.

Comment: so you're asking how to remove a watermark... state that clearly. **do not** be vague. in fact, add some pictures that aren't just mockups but actual data. -- [edit] your question. clearly state which quantities are known and which are unknown (known: image_i, overlay, unknown: alpha, base_i). present _usable_ equations, like `image_i = base_i + (overlay-base_i) * alpha` (blending equation) -- given what you've said so far, *which isn't much*, this is **not solvable**. you'd need a bunch more constraints/information. -- and please review [ask] and [mre]. show your research and your attempts.

Comment: While you are correct that this description matches a watermark, what I want to remove is a GPS trace over a map. I tried to describe the problem in a general way as I do not know enough about image processing to know which information is needed. I was hoping for an answer pointing me in the right direction. Do you have examples of what else I need to supply?

Comment: It seems like you have N equations and N+1 unknowns, so it’s not perfectly solvable. You will need to add some constraints to attempt to solve it.

Comment: good old 4chan mantra: pics or GT... -- this is a visual problem. I'm always amazed when people try to solve visual problems with talking. :) and *yes* you must give specific details (like pics, or a **video** if your pictures *move* instead of being entirely unrelated to each other). leave that to the philosophers and politicians.